# What's happening with this formset?

Tags: django

I created a *formset* using a *queryset*.

Just before I render the template with the *formset*, I update the records the *queryset* returned in such a way that they no longer would have met the *queryset's* filter criteria.

If I do "something" (i.e. `print(formset)` or `num_forms = formset.total_form_count())` w/ the *formset* prior to rendering the template, it returns all of the records the original query returns.

If I don't do something w/ the *formset* prior to rendering the template, the *formset* is empty.

Easy enough for me to leave some arbitrary operation in the code but would love to understand what's going on here.

Code from views.py:

```
batch = (Ad.objects.filter(
                  (Q(labeler_expiration__lt=timezone.now()) | Q(labeler_expiration__isnull=True))
                  & Q(category__isnull=True))
                  .order_by('id')[:25]
                )

formset = AdFormSet(queryset=batch)

#Here I need to do something w/ the formset:
num_forms = formset.total_form_count()
#print(formset) #This print could also work instead of the line above

(Ad.objects.filter(pk__in=batch.values('pk'))
.update(labeler=request.user.labeler, labeler_expiration=(timezone.now() + timedelta(minutes=25))))


return render(request, 'label_ads_batch.html', {'formset': formset})
```

Comment: I'm thinking that operations on the formset which used the queryset must cause the queryset to become cached (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets).

Comment: I don't understand your question. You explicitly update the expiration dates, so why are you surprised they no longer match?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @DanielRoseman. When I leave in 'num_forms = formset.total_form_count()' and/or 'print(formset)', the formset returns all of the original queryset's records from prior to the update. If I remove the 'num_forms =....' and the 'print(formset)', the formset is empty. The act of using the formset in any way prior to the update has them available at the time of the render call. I believe the "using" of the formset puts the queryset into cache but trying to understand what's going on here more.